# How to enable the UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have two `viewcontroller`s in a storyboard. The first view is the `LaunchScreen`, which appears first. With `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` the second View will be displayed.

The first time the second view is displayed my code of the second view is checking a flag if a file exists. The second view has a `UIButton` which is disabled if the file doesn't exist. If I close the second view with

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

the second view disappears and I see my first view. It works well.

But if I repeat it and the second view appears, the `viewcontroller` doesn't check the flag I changed, because the file exists now.

The following method

```
-(void)showConfigView {
    [self presentViewController:[self config] animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

is calling the second View.

My question is: **Why is my `UIButton` still disabled although the flag has another value and the file exist ?**

Comment: Where (in which method of your second view) exactly do you check for this flag?

Comment: May be the way you check the flag is wrong, you need to do something before present like: secondViewController.flag = self.flag, use delegate, notification or has an instance of firstViewController in your secondViewController to get flag value.  Look like you checking flag value in -viewDidLoad method? try to change to -viewDidAppear.

Comment: @sticker/@rokjarc2: I check the flag in -viewDidLoad.

Comment: - viewDidLoad only run one time, move your code to viewWillAppear or -viewDidAppear

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Change flag in both, viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is to check the flag each time the view controller is **closed** or **shown**. You can do it in `showConfigView` before calling `presentViewController` or before `dismissViewControllerAnimated` if it is what you are using.

But the best practice is to check conditions in `viewWillAppear` or in `viewDidLoad`.

To enable the button you write

```
  .userInteractionEnabled = true;
```

Comment: Thanks, Objective-C is new for me. I check the conditions in -viewWillAppear now.

Comment: It helps me to understand how it works and it works too. I want to understand how it works. I doesn't thought Objective-C is so hard. C and C++ was easier to learn :D

Comment: @Premox you can try **Swift** for iOS development, it is way easier for beginners.

Comment: @Premox could you please accept my answer instead of the one selected? It is obvious that my one is more competent, judging by the votes

Answer (score 0):

```
  .userInteractionEnabled = true;     
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

> please try it. This code writes when you close or dismiss second view.